# Find the Riemann-Stieltjes integral

Tags: real-analysis, integration, functional-analysis, analysis, definite-integrals

Let $g(x) = $ sin $x$ for $\ 0 \le \ x \le \pi/2 $ 
Find
$$
\int_0^\frac \pi 2 xdg
$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**(1)** Here's a hint: if the distribution function of the Riemann-Stieltjes measure is differentiable, it has a density, and hence is absolutely continuous with respect to Lebesgue measure -- in other words:

$$
\int_0^\frac \pi 2 x\text{d}g = \int_0^\frac{\pi}{2} x g'(x) \text{d}x=\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2}x \cos(x) \text{d} x
$$

Now use integration by parts, and you will be done.

**(2)** What is probably simpler then reducing to the regular Riemann integral and using the Riemann integration by parts formula is to use the Riemann-Stieltjes integration by parts formula directly.

This formula is:

$$\int_a^b f(x) \text{d} g(x) = f(b)g(b) - f(a)g(a)-\int_a^b g(x)\text{d}f(x)$$

Here we have $f(x)=x$ and $g(x)=sin(x)$ as well as $a=0$ and $b= \frac{\pi}{2}$. Hence the answer is:

$$\frac{\pi}{2}sin(\frac{\pi}{2}) - 0*0 - \int_0^\frac{\pi}{2} \sin(x) \text{d}x = \frac{\pi}{2} - (-cos x)|_0^{\pi}{2} = \frac{\pi}{2} -1$$

**Exercise:** Show that the answer from **(1)** agrees with that derived in **(2)**. (See: [here](http://www2.clarku.edu/~djoyce/ma121/parts.pdf))